# Linux java, max disk space size of file

Tags: java, linux

I want to ask, if:

`-Xms1000M -Xmx1000M`

Are commands for Java (Linux) for maximum file usage of RAM, is there opinion to do same with Disc space?

Example to set max file size at running it, same as for RAM, just for HDD/SSD space.

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: They are not for "file usage" of RAM. They set the initial and maximum size of the heap in memory. Java may use additional non-heap memory that's not controlled by this. There is no similar setting for files because the files you use are not really part of the operation of the JVM itself. But there are OS facilities for such limitations.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Hey, thanks for answer, what are solutions then for making limit with OS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the `-Xms1000M` and `-Xmx1000M` do not set a limit on the JVM's usage of RAM.  They set the initial size and limit for the Java heap ... where regular objects are held.   A JVM uses RAM for many other things that are not regular objects; e.g. stacks, metaspace, space used by the executable and various kinds of off-heap allocations, and so on.  These are not limited by `-Xms` and `-Xmx`.

To answer your actual question: Java does not provide a way to limit the amount of disk space consumed by a program.

On Linux / UNIX you can limit the size of files written via the shell builtin command `ulimit`.  (The limit that controls this is the `-s` limit.)  However, since this is a builtin command that limits the current shell and its child process, using `Process` to run `bash -c ulimit` is not going to be effective.   The command must be run *before* you launch the JVM.

To answer the question that you *might* have been trying to ask:  Java doesn't provide a way to limit the total RAM used either.  But you can do this with `ulimit`; see above.